# static const vector without new actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, static, actionscript, constants

I have written some code in `Flash Actionscript 3`

```
public class someClass 
{
    public static const someVector:Vector.<anotherClass> = Vector. <anotherClass> ([staticConstInstance1, staticConstInstance2, staticConstInstance3]);
}
```

and it works as intended, but if I use the following code which i tried before using above code (The only diffrence is the new Keyword)

```
public class someClass 
{
    public static const someVector:Vector.<anotherClass> = new Vector.<anotherClass> ([staticConstInstance1, staticConstInstance2, staticConstInstance3]);
}
```

then it does not work. Could someone please explain to me why the new Keyword makes the difference here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to populate a Vector is:

```
public static const someVector:Vector.<anotherClass> = new <anotherClass>[staticConstInstance1, staticConstInstance2, staticConstInstance3];
```

In your first example you just cast an array to a Vector (which I guess would be slower than to populate it properly).

Comment: Thank you! I now understood the problem i had.